# Problem With Change Before Play Icon When Playing Next Music In The RecyclerView

Tags: adapter, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

im new to android developing.
i have two list of musics that i can completely getting and playing and changing that's icon from play to pause or etc.
but i have a major problem with my before playing item.
for resolving this problem i was searching all of my past day and today and reading a lot codes to find best condition for changing.

Main Trouble:
when im clicking for the first on play_btn , my music starting to play. its OK.
when im clicking on play_btn playing music , it change icon to pause and its music will stop;
**truble when im clicking on next recycler row . my past btn_play icon dont changing.**

```
viewHolder.btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

    if (oldPosition == -1) {
      if (!isMediaPlayerPlaying) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        switch (listName) {
          case "sabah": {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(G.app, sabahMusics.get(position));
            break;
          }
          case "masae": {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(G.app, masaeMusics.get(position));
            break;
          }
        }
        Log.i("hdev", "boolean is: " + isMediaPlayerPlaying);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        isMediaPlayerPlaying = !isMediaPlayerPlaying;
        oldPosition = position;
      } else {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        isMediaPlayerPlaying = !isMediaPlayerPlaying;
      }
    }
    if (oldPosition != position) {

    }

      if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          viewHolder.btn_play.setBackground(G.app.getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
        }
      } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          viewHolder.btn_play.setBackground(G.app.getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
        }
      }

      mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          Log.i("hdev", "Prepaired Prepaired Prepaired");
        }
      });
      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            viewHolder.btn_play.setBackground(G.app.getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
          }
        }
      });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im answerd this question with limitting my users:

```
viewHolder.btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    takeView = view;
    if (oldPosition == -1 || oldPosition == position) {
      if (!isMediaPlayerPlaying) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        switch (listName) {
          case "sabah": {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(G.app, sabahMusics.get(position));
            break;
          }
          case "masae": {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(G.app, masaeMusics.get(position));
            break;
          }
        }
        Log.i("hdev", "boolean is: " + isMediaPlayerPlaying);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        isMediaPlayerPlaying = !isMediaPlayerPlaying;
        oldPosition = position;
      } else {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        oldPosition = -1;
        isMediaPlayerPlaying = !isMediaPlayerPlaying;
      }
      if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          viewHolder.btn_play.setBackground(G.app.getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
        }
      } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          viewHolder.btn_play.setBackground(G.app.getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
        }
      }
      mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          Log.i("hdev", "Prepaired Prepaired Prepaired");
        }
      });
      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            viewHolder.btn_play.setBackground(G.app.getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
          }
        }
      });
    } else  {
      MediaPlayer waterMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      waterMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      waterMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(G.app, R.raw.water);
      waterMediaPlayer.start();
      animateShake(viewHolder.btn_play);
      Snackbar.make(view.getRootView() ,"Something to show Err for user", 2000).show();

    }
  }
});
```